# How do I compare if list of files from one directory exist in second directory and copy them to third directory?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a list of 100 files in directory1 with .dll extension:

```
directory1/file1.dll
directory1/file2.dll
...
directory1/file100.dll
```

There is another, directory2, with 10000 files with .dll extension, located among many subdirectories:

```
directory2/subdirectory1/file1.dll
directory2/subdirectory2/file3.dll
...
directory2/subdirectory3/file10000.dll
```

I need to compare if 100 files of same name from directory1 exist in directory2 and then copy found ones to directory3.

How can I do it in most efficient way?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: can a given file (eg, `file1.dll`) show up multilpe times under `directory2`? do you need to compare any other attributes of the files (eg, must the contents be identical)? which file are you looking to copy ... the file from `directory1` or the file from `directory2`? do you already have the 2 lists of files or do you also need to know how to find the list of files?

Comment: SO is not a code writing service; you're expected to show your effort (eg, research, code); consider reviewing [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then come back and update the question accordingly; in particular, show the code you've tried so far and the (incorrect) output generated by your code

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have no spaces (or other unpleasant chars in filenames):

```
cd /path/to/first_directory
for file in *.dll; do
    find /path/to/second_directory/ -name "$file" | xargs -I ABCD cp ABCD /path/to/third_dir
done
```

`find` goes through subdirectories. ABCD is placeholder. You can see details in `man xargs`:

> ```
> -I replace-str
> ```
>
> Replace  occurrences  of  replace-str in the initial-arguments with names read from standard input.  Also, unquoted blanks do not terminate input items; instead the separator is the newline character.  Implies `-x` and `-L 1`.

Comment: `for file in *.dll`. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: See [Bash Pitfalls #1 (for f in $(ls *.mp3))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

dir1=directory1
dir2=directory2
dir3=directory3

shopt -s dotglob globstar nullglob

# Set up an associative array to record which files are in "$dir1"
declare -A is_in_dir1
for path in "$dir1"/*.dll; do
    file=${path##*/}
    is_in_dir1[$file]=1
done

for path in "$dir2"/**/*.dll; do
    file=${path##*/}
    if (( ${is_in_dir1[$file]-0} )); then
        cp -n -v -- "$path" "$dir3"
    fi
done
```

- You'll need to change the `dir1`, `dir2`, and `dir3` settings.
- `shopt -s` sets some Bash configurations required by the code:

  - `dotglob` causes glob patterns (e.g. `*.dll`) to match names that begin with `.`.  You might not want that.
  - `globstar` enables the use of `**` to match paths recursively through directory trees.
  - `nullglob` makes globs expand to nothing when nothing matches (otherwise they expand to the glob pattern itself, which is almost never useful in programs).
- See [BashGuide/Arrays - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays) (last section) for information about associative arrays in Bash.
- See [Removing part of a string (BashFAQ/100 (How do I do string manipulation in bash?))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string) for an explanation of `${path##*/}`.
- See [glob - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) for information about globbing in general, and `globstar` and the  `**` pattern in particular.
- The code should work with any file or directory names (including ones with spaces or newlines in them).
- I can't say that the code implements the "most efficient way", but it scans both `"$dir1"` and `"$dir2"` only once and I can't think of a way to make it significantly faster.